# How can I get user Input via Command Line?

Tags: javascript, command-line, casperjs

I'm running CasperJS using Windows' command line and I would like to know how to get user's input using the command line.

I would like to ask the user for information during the script's execution or pass an argument before running the script, for example:

```
casperjs test test.js my_argument_here
```

Comment: Umm, write a one-line shell script? `capserjs test test.js $1`?

Comment: @torazaburo - he wants to know how to see the args -- not how to invoke it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done more research about this subject and discovered that I can't create my own casper object inside the tester module.

Here's what I've done (just In case there's anyone with the same problem):

I included this on my test.js file:

```
var url = casper.cli.get("url")
```

And now I run it through the command line like this:

```
casperjs test test.js --url="http://google.com"
```

Thank you all for your responses.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the test suite you probably want to just use an include file.

In file include.me.js

```
casper.my_params = {
      "arg1" : "val1",
      "arg2" : "val2"  // etc
};
```

Then on the command line run like this:

```
casperjs test file.js --includes=include.me.js
```

`casper.my_params.arg1` and `casper.my_params.arg2` will be available

---

Clearly documented here using the cli object: http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/cli.html

```
var casper = require("casper").create();

casper.echo("Casper CLI passed args:");
require("utils").dump(casper.cli.args);

casper.echo("Casper CLI passed options:");
require("utils").dump(casper.cli.options);

casper.exit();
```

Comment: I'm using CasperJS test module.
I cannot instantiate a casper object this way.

I get this error:

Test file: portal.js
Fatal: you can't override the preconfigured casper instance in a test environment.
Docs: http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/testing.html#test-command-args-and-options

Comment: just take out the var line... the casper object already exists.

Comment: I keep getting an ÔÜá┬á┬áCasperError: Invalid test path: arg1.
I just added this ( require("utils").dump(casper.cli.args); ) to my casper start function (which was working properly before) and it isn't working yet.
I'm trying to run it like this: casperjs test file.js arg1 arg2

Comment: @lucasfcosta see use of `--includes` above

Answer (score 0):

`casper.cli.options` will provide that.

http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/cli.html